# give a recursive definition when 'show'ing 'string' elements

Tags: string, list, haskell

I have the following function:

```
convertToStr :: [Int] -> String
convertToStr [] = []
convertToStr (int:ints)
    | length (int:ints) == 1 = ((show (head (drop 0 (int:ints)))) ++ ", ")
    | length (int:ints) == 2 = ((show (head (drop 0 (int:ints)))) ++ ", ") ++ ((show (head (drop 1 (int:ints)))) ++ ", ")
```

As can be seen above, I have managed to get the following output from this input:

```
> convertToStr [3,5]
"3, 5, "
```

I seem, however to be stuck with regard to being able to write a recursive definition. I'd like to convert a list of any length in `[Int]` elements to a string with that list and not have it limited as such.

Comment: Do realize that `drop 0` does basically nothing. It takes a list, and drops 0 elements from it. Also, you should try to get more comfortable with [pattern matching](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#pattern-matching).

Comment: This sounds like homework; the basic idea is convert the first number, then use recursion to convert the rest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without explicit recursion you can do it using `map` and [intersperse](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Data-List.html#v%3Aintersperse) like this

```
convertToString :: [Int] -> String
convertToString = concat . (intersperse ", ") . map show
```

Edit: And with manual recursion it's like

```
cts [] = ""
cts (x:xs)
   | null xs = show x 
   | otherwise = show x ++ ", " ++ cts xs
```

Comment: With this approach I'd personally prefer pattern matching `[x]` rather than using the `null xs` guard.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your function is a bit messy. I would suggest you to have a look at some library functions for your task. I suggest [`intercalate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3aintercalate), which  takes a list of lists (strings), puts something between them (like `", "`) and concats them.